# Shortcut on desktop for all users of a single computer using GPO

Tags: shortcuts, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a particular machine that is joined to our domain, and no matter which user logs onto that machine, they all need to have access to a common shortcut (on the desktop).

If any user logs onto a different machine, they do not need to see that shortcut on their desktop.

How can I implement this using GPO?

I have tried creating a GPO that targets the specific machine, and creating the shortcut in both the Computer and User policy branches, but despite the policy being applied, the shortcut never appears. Thanks!

***UPDATED TO ADD***

In response to the comment below from @phuclv, yes you can use GPO to create shortcuts ... https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2014/02/17/adding-shortcuts-on-desktop-using-group-policy-preferences-in-windows-8-and-windows-8-1/

Comment: GPO deals with policy and not shortcuts. Why don't just put those into `%PUBLIC%\Desktop`?

Comment: Because in future, there may be multiple computers that require this same setup, and rather than logging into each computer and adding them manually, I would like to use GPO to automate the process as much as possible.

Comment: you said you "have a single machine", which means that it's unlikely there's a domain to join, and it'll be easier to just create the shortcut in the public desktop

Comment: A single machine that is domain joined! Sorry for not being clearer. Will add that to my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did to make it work!

- Create a new GPO "Test GPO"
- "Test GPO" > Computer Configuration > Preferences > Windows Settings > Shortcuts > Add >

  - { Replace, "Test Shortcut", File System Object, All Users Desktop "\\Path\To\Folder" }
- Delegation > Advanced > Authenticated Users > Apply Group Policy > Unchecked/Unticked
- Delegation > Advanced > Add > TESTCOMPUTER
- Delegation > Advanced > TESTCOMPUTER > Apply Group Policy > Checked/Ticked

Pretty sure I tried this combination before(!) but it's working now so who knows!